# How to add more fontify rules

Tags: font-lock

I'm following the instruction at 
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AllOut#toc3
to have the `allout` mode fontify its headers (enclosed below).

It works but the existing major mode's fontifying effort would be gone. Is it possible to have them both?

```el
(defvar rf-allout-font-lock-keywords
  '(;;
    ;; Highlight headings according to the level.
    (eval . (list (concat "^\\(" outline-regexp "\\).+")
        0 '(or (cdr (assq (outline-depth)
                  '((1 . font-lock-function-name-face)
                    (2 . font-lock-variable-name-face)
                    (3 . font-lock-keyword-face)
                    (4 . font-lock-builtin-face)
                    (5 . font-lock-comment-face)
                    (6 . font-lock-constant-face)
                    (7 . font-lock-type-face)
                    (8 . font-lock-string-face))))
               font-lock-warning-face)
        nil t)))
  "Additional expressions to highlight in Outline mode.")

;; add font-lock to allout mode
(defun rf-allout-font-lock-hook ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'font-lock-defaults)
       '(rf-allout-font-lock-keywords t nil nil outline-back-to-current-heading)))

(add-hook 'outline-mode-hook 'rf-allout-font-lock-hook)
```

Answer (score 3):

The code on the web page is a bit outdated. You spotted that it replaces existing syntax highlighting. In addition, it uses functions (`outline-depth`) which doesn't seem to exist in modern Emacs versions. The code below reimplements this using `font-lock-add-keywords`. Also, it doesn't use the `eval` form, as it typically is only used in extreme situations where keywords can't be formed when the hook is called, fortunately, this isn't the case here.

```el
(defun my-allout-mode-hook ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil
   `((,(concat "^\\(" outline-regexp "\\).+")
      (0 (or (cdr (assq (- (match-end 1) (match-beginning 1))
                        '((1 . font-lock-function-name-face)
                          (2 . font-lock-variable-name-face)
                          (3 . font-lock-keyword-face)
                          (4 . font-lock-builtin-face)
                          (5 . font-lock-comment-face)
                          (6 . font-lock-constant-face)
                          (7 . font-lock-type-face)
                          (8 . font-lock-string-face))))
             font-lock-warning-face)))))
  (if (fboundp 'font-lock-flush)
      (font-lock-flush)
    (when font-lock-mode
      (with-no-warnings
        (font-lock-fontify-buffer)))))

(add-hook 'allout-mode-hook 'my-allout-mode-hook)
```